# value is not a member of type parameter F[]

Tags: scala, monads, functor, scala-cats

I have this code:

```
trait ModelDataService[F[_]] {
  def getModelVersion(modelVersionId: Long): F[ModelVersion]
}

class ModelDataServiceIdInterpreter[F[_] : Monad] extends ModelDataService[F] {
  override def getModelVersion(modelVersionId: Long): F[ModelVersion] = {
    val mv = ModelVersion(1, 1, "ModelType", "Status", None, None, Some(ModelContract("ModelName", Some(ModelSignature("infer", Seq(ModelField(name="blah", profile=DataProfileType.NUMERICAL)), Seq.empty[ModelField])))), None, "", None)
    Monad[F].pure(mv)
  }
}
```

I am trying to do this:

```
    val model = modelDataService.getModelVersion(modelVersionId)
    val batchSize = model.monitoringConfiguration
```

I get a compile error

```
 value monitoringConfiguration is not a member of type parameter F[a.grpc.entities.ModelVersion]
```

However, `a.grpc.entities.ModelVersion` has the `monitoringConfiguration` field. I guess it has something to do with `F`. Is there a way I can access the `batchSize` inside `model`?

Comment: So `F[A]` is not the same as `A`, the same way than red is not the same thing as yellow. You do not have a **ModelVersion** you have a **ModelVersion** wrapped inside some effect. Which one? we do not know yet, since the caller is free to provide any effect they want as long as such effect has an instance of a **Monad** associated with it. - So you may be asking, ok, but then how can I use that effect thing? The answer would be using the **Monad** API, so probably through operations like `map` & `flatMap`.

Comment: However, if you didn't know this, then probably is because you also do not know how to work with concrete _effects_ like **Option** or **Future**; or maybe you do but this is your first time writing code that is abstract to the effect. In any case, I would recommend you to study more about this topic, it seems you are working on a codebase that someone else wrote, maybe you can ask for mentoring or training from those people? If not, then you may want to search in the internet about functional programming in **Scala**, the book Scala with Cats is great as a starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on constraints that you have over your higher-kinded type `F`. If your `F` is a functor, then you can access the value inside using `map`. If `F` is a `FlatMap`, or a `Monad`, you can also use `flatMap`.

```scala
val batchSize: F[Long] =
  modelDataService
    .getModelVersion(modelVersionId)
    .map(_.monitoringConfiguration)
```

The way the program is structured is that your value will be inside of `F` at all times, until you really need to get it out. And that is done by initiation of `F` to some concrete type, e.g. `IO` from cats-effect, or `Future` from native scala library. Or if you don't perform any side-effects, it can be as simple as `Option`. Once the type is concrete, you have different ways of getting the value out, depending on the type. For `Future` it can be `.onComplete`, for `Option` it can be `.getOrElse`, etc.

```
val service: ModelDataService[Option] = new ModelDataServiceIdInterpreter[Option]
val maybeBatchSize: Option[Long] =
  modelDataService
    .getModelVersion(modelVersionId)
    .map(_.monitoringConfiguration)

val batchSizeDefaultValue = 10L
val batchSize = maybeBatchSize.getOrElse(batchSizeDefaultValue)
```